# Passing Map<String, Set<String>> from Servlet to JSP Select

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, select

I have a `map<String, Set<String>>`. I trying to pass the values for this object from servlet to jsp.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> filter_info= new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
for(String key: results.keySet())
{
    filter_info.put(key.trim(), new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(results.get(key).split(","))));

}
request.setAttribute("filter",filter_info);
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Search.jsp")
                .forward(request, response);
```

I have two select inputs in my jsp. I am trying to make the options (values of `Set<String>`) of the second select to change depending on the option (`key`) selected in the first select.

```
<form role="search" class="search-form" id="search-form" action="#" method="post">

     <label for="Keys">Keys: </label>
       <select id="Keys">
            <c:forEach var="filter" items="${filter}">
              <option value="${filter.key}">
                <c:out  value="${filter.key}"/>
              </option>
            </c:forEach>
       </select>
        <br/>
     <label for="SetValues">Values: </label>
         <select id="SetValues">
         //the part I don't know how to change according to the key selected
         </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="search-button">
</form>
```

The question is: do I need javascript or can I do it whith passing and casting the object sent in the request, for example `Map<String, Set<String>> filter= (HashMap<String, Set<String>>) request.getAttribute("servletName");`, then iterate through it and prepare the two selects ?

Thanks.

Comment: In the way you have your code its not possible to make your goal, because first iterate all keys, then build the dropdown by key...maybe you have to iterate again all keys and for each key extract the Set and build the specific dropdown

Comment: @cralfaro I will try your suggestion; the problem is I don't know which key is selected so as to change the values. And I am not bound to one way, I can change the code if you have a different way to make it work.

Comment: Actually i would chose a different approach, as you need a first dropdown and the second one its loaded depending on the value of the first, I would add an onChange event in the first dropdown, and then make an ajax call to the server to load the right values for the second dropdown, your code will be cleaner and easier to mantain.

Comment: if you change selected key in first Select,  you want to change the second dropdown without refreshing ?

Comment: @cralfaro I am currently try you suggestion.

Comment: @Deyd yes.
-----

Comment: @M20 if you need any help, or doubt let me know.

Comment: you can't do that without using javascript (ajax call).

Comment: @cralfaro thanks for your help. It worked. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to get your goal its

1. First iterate over all key of your Set and build the first dropdown

   ```
    <label for="Keys">Keys: </label>
      <select id="Keys" onchange="updateByKey()">
           <c:forEach var="filter" items="${filter}">
             <option value="${filter.key}">
               <c:out  value="${filter.key}"/>
             </option>
           </c:forEach>
      </select>
       <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="search-button">
   ```
2. Add an onChange event to the first dropdown and with every change make an ajax call to the server and retrieve the right values and build the second dropdown

   ```
   <label for="SetValues">Values: </label>
         //here load the dropdown with all options of the selected key in the previous dropdown
   <select id="SetValues">
       //iterate all options of this specific key
   </select>
   ```